# Ms Access and SQL: error when executing calculations on query outputs

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to run a query that performs a calculation using other queries' output and some user inputs.

The query code is below:

```
SELECT (qryCurrentMaterialCost.CurrentMaterialCost
        *([Forms]![Should Cost Tool]![List41]/100)
        *([Forms]![Should Cost Tool]![List60]/
         qryPriceAluminumSelectedDate.PriceAtSelectedDate)) AS Expr1
FROM qryPriceAluminumSelectedDate, qryCurrentMaterialCost;
```

This gives me two errors below:

[image]

[image]
If too small to read:

> The record source ' ' specified on this form or report doe snot exist.
>   The name of the recordsource may be misspelled, the recordsource was
>   deleted or renamed, or the recordsource exists in a different
>   database. In the form or report's design view or layout view, display
>   the propery sheet by clicking the properties button, and then set the
>   recordsource property to an existing table or query.

Notes:

- All list boxes are placed on a form called *Should Cost Tool*
- All queries used in the query above work fine separately.
- *List41* is a percentage that the user provides (format is integer,
  hence the division by 100).
- List 60 is the CURRENT price of the aluminum commodity, also provided
  by the user
- The query *qryCurrentMaterialCost* calculates a value called *Current
  Material Cost* using two user inputs. This is the code:

  ```
  SELECT ([Forms]![Should Cost Tool]![List39]*
         ([Forms]![Should Cost Tool]![List40]/100)) AS CurrentMaterialCost;
  ```
- The query *qryPriceAluminumSelectedDate* returns the price of the
  aluminum commodity for a past date, this past date is selected by the
  user.The code for this one is:

  ```
  SELECT [Item Master].DateStamp 
  FROM [Item Master] 
  WHERE [Item Master].MaterialID=[Forms]![History Supplier Tool]![List16]  
  UNION
  SELECT ZMCE.PODate 
  FROM ZMCE  
  WHERE ZMCE.MaterialID=[Forms]![History Supplier Tool]![List16];
  ```

Comment: The source for your original query, contains 2 queries that are separated by a comma in the from clause. You need to join these 2 queries

Comment: But both queries simply produce an output. I'm not sure how to join these?  I mean thhe second query does not use data from any tables, it only uses user inputs. Hence I have no table columns for that one to join with the other query. I'm fairly new at SQL, so my apologies if what I'm asking is basic.

Comment: @random_answer_guy a JOIN should not be required. This will make the Cartesian product of the two tables/queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use one query, the UNION query, with calculated column of the form controls. Error pointed to the query without a `FROM` clause. While you can save such as query, you cannot reference it in another one since it does not contain a source table.

Below names calculated column, *CurrentMaterialCost*, which MS Access SQL allows to be referenced in other columns of same query.

```
SELECT ([Forms]![Should Cost Tool]![List39] *
       ([Forms]![Should Cost Tool]![List40]/100)) AS CurrentMaterialCost,
       ([CurrentMaterialCost] * ([Forms]![Should Cost Tool]![List41]/100)
        * ([Forms]![Should Cost Tool]![List60]/
         qryPriceAluminumSelectedDate.PriceAtSelectedDate)) AS Expr1
FROM qryPriceAluminumSelectedDate;
```

Even then, there is no need for such a column referencing as you can integrate calculation in larger expression:

```
SELECT (
        ([Forms]![Should Cost Tool]![List39] *
        ([Forms]![Should Cost Tool]![List40]/100))
       ) * ([Forms]![Should Cost Tool]![List41]/100)
         * ([Forms]![Should Cost Tool]![List60]/
         qryPriceAluminumSelectedDate.PriceAtSelectedDate) AS Expr1
FROM qryPriceAluminumSelectedDate;
```